# How to play "the job interview game" so that I maximize the probability of getting the job?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

When I started to look for a job, I believed that companies and candidates were honest when they are looking to hire someone or get employed. I thought that the candidate which is the best fit for the job gets the job. Obviously, it's up to the company to assess the best fit and sometimes they can make the wrong decision, but usually the person most suited for the job gets the job.

I was wrong. There are other factors which come into play, such as timing (did you apply for the job as soon as the job listing came out or later), company's honesty (is the company just keeping the job listing open for some unknown reason and they have no intention to hire someone at all), to reveal or not to reveal your financial expectations etc. I have come to learn that there are "games" the companies are playing with the candidates. These "games" companies play can not only result in not getting the offer, even though you as a candidate did great, but there are other things which can happen: you getting a "low-ball" salary because you managed the financial part of the interview poorly etc.

In order to illustrate one of these "games" I will use a concrete example:

> Candidate A and Candidate B have roughly the same experience and have
> done similarly well in the interview process. The company which is
> hiring prefers Candidate A over Candidate B. The company schedules the
> candidates such that Candidate A comes before Candidate B. Assume that
> the company schedules Candidate A a week or so in advance before Candidate B. As
> Candidate B is in the final round of the interview, the company
> already sent an offer to Candidate A and is awaiting their response.
> Candidate B can only pass if Candidate A rejects the offer.

Now, imagine the alternative scenario:

> Candidate A and Candidate B have roughly the same experience and have
> done similarly well in the interview process. The company which is
> hiring prefers Candidate A over Candidate B. The company schedules the
> candidates such that Candidate A comes before Candidate B, but
> Candidate B emphasizes they can't interview on that scheduled time due
> to some reasons. They can only interview earlier. So now, Candidate
> B's interview is pushed in the same week as the Candidate A's
> interview (maybe even the same day) and now the company is in a much
> harder position since they have to stall Candidate B much longer (with
> the risk of them taking another offer or quitting the hiring process.
> In this situation, the company is in
> a harder position that in the previous example.

Obviously, this gets more complicated as more candidates are involved, but in the second example, Candidate B "stirred things up" and they put the odds in their favor, because the company hiring for the position is a bit "off-balance": the risk of losing both candidates is higher in the 2nd scenario than in the 1st scenario.

So my question is: **As a candidate for a job, what can I do to stack the odds in my favor?** Don't get me wrong; I firmly believe that really knowing your craft is the #1 way to land a job, but I also want to "play the job interview game" so that the company has the least amount of manipulation space, if of course they are manipulative.

Comment: What the heck do you think you are gaining by using the "alternative scenario"? You may be making life more difficult for the company, but you still aren't going to get the job unless candidate A turns it down. And you've wasted an interview. And almost any company is going to interview you if you are somewhere close to candidate A's standard. Then they prefer to interview you sooner. I think this game you have invented is all in your head. "Stirring things up" doesn't get you any benefit.

Answer (score 5):

I have very recently gone through the hiring process.

I abhor 'games' - I said straight up the reason I was looking (current company not able to meet market rates for the position I was in and my skills and experience).

Now, Some companies are off-put by that, that's fine - that's their prerogative. Other companies however saw that I was up-front and wasn't being deceptive about my motivations in looking to move. When I had my interviews with them and discussed things about me - one of the points I raised was that I am honest and am not one to lie to protect feelings.

This combined with what they had witnessed first hand told them about the nature of my character.

The point being here: Don't try to pretend you are something or not. It might work once perhaps twice - but eventually you'll get caught out. If you have to change yourself *fundamentally* to get a shot at working for a company - my life experience has told me it's probably not a company you want to work for.

For reference, I've got long hair and a massive beard and although I braid it when interviewing - some people still don't like facial hair. One recruiter raised this to me once - my response was an emphatic 'If they have an issue with it, then they aren't the sort of people I want to work for'.

Don't play games, be yourself.

And the Caveat - if who you are as a person needs to be better - work on that.

Answer (score 2):

> but I also want to "play the job interview game" so that the company has the least amount of manipulation space, if of course they are manipulative.

So you win the manipulation game and get hired and then what?  You are likely going to end up playing manipulation games throughout your career at this company.  If you are OK with that then by all means continue to play games for the rest of your life.

How a company hires is usually a reflection of how the company operates.  The good ones don't need to manipulate their potential candidates nor do they need to manipulate their employees.  If you come across a company in your job search that is employing these tactics, that is a red flag.

Rather than wasting time trying to learn how to out-manipulate a manipulative company, just focus on your skills and experience and be yourself when interviewing for any position.  The ones that cannot accept you for what you truly have to offer are likely not worth working for.

Answer (score 1):

There are two strategies you need to be using:

First, you need to use internal referrals. Network with others. Go to meetups. Use your LinkedIn. Ask for introductions to your second degree contacts. A resume with a referral is much more likely to lead to an interview. Also, an internal referral is much more likely to give you the inside scoop about the current hiring situation.

And second, you need to apply to as many companies as possible, and never stop applying until you have a signed contract and a starting date. Sadly, many job-hunters stop looking at other potential employers as soon as they're close to closing a deal with a potential employer.

In other words, if you want to be unaffected by their games, you need to generate as many offers of your own as you can. And when the finish line is near, you can't start slowing down, you need to do the opposite and speed up.